# How can i detect whether two CALayers overlap?

Tags: ios, ipad

In my app the user can drag the top CALayer from a stack of CALayers.

When the users stops dragging the CALayer should return to its original position on top of the others CALayers. Unless the CALayer (after dragging) no longer overlaps with the other CALayers in which case it should move underneath the other CALayers.

Now, how can I detect whether two CALayers overlap?

Answer (score 1):

CALayer's frame property is a CGRect. Fortunately for you, CGGeometry has the following method:

CGRectIntersectsRect

You'd use it like this:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(myLayer1.frame,myLayer2.frame)) {

//code

}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaan, this helped me out!